# Error with Async/Await Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am getting the following error while trying some `async` methods.  I am following this example: [Microsoft Async Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/06/26/understanding-a-simple-async-program.aspx)

> 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

The method the 'await' is in IS async and I think it's pretty much the same as the Microsoft example.

What I am doing wrong here?

**Button Click**

```
private void btn_Async_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeneralFeatures gf = new GeneralFeatures();
        Task<long> getLongRunningData = gf._Async();

        long answer = await getLongRunningData ;
    }
```

**Async Method**

```
class GeneralFeatures
{
public async Task<long> _Async()
    {
        /////  LONG RUNNING TASK  /////////
        int count = 0;
        int j = 1101000;
        long a = 2;
        while (count < j)
        {
            long b = 2;
            int prime = 1;// to check if found a prime
            while (b * b <= a)
            {
                if (a % b == 0)
                {
                    prime = 0;
                    break;
                }
                b++;
            }
            if (prime > 0)
                count++;
            a++;
        }
        /////  LONG RUNNING TASK  /////////

        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: `private void btn_Async_Click` Tell me exactly where you define it as `async`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `await` if the method signature does not have `async`.

no `async` in `private void btn_Async_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

should be : `private async void btn_Async_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` give that a try, or call an async method from that one.

Comment: Indeed. And this matches the example on the linked page which has `private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) ` as the first method signature.

Comment: @Chris no need to look, it was obviously missing :)

Comment: That wasn't meant as supporting evidence of why your answer was right but as a highlight to the OP of where his code was different from that which he thought he was copying. As you say your answer quite happily stands without need for external references.